# A toolbox with code for context free grammar verificiation for logical formulas

Tags: machine-learning

I work with Linear Temporal Logic [(LTL) formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic). I am looking for a toolbox to verify if an LTL formula can satisfy a given Context-Free Grammar (CFG).

For example, we have the LTL formula **G(x_1>0)**. In that LTL formula, **G** is the temporal operator **always** (or **globally**), and x_1 is the first mode of a finite trajectory of binary values.

For example, **x:=1,0,1; 1,1,1; 1,1,0**. This trajectory satisfies **G(x_1>0)** because **x_1** (the first mode) is alsway true (the first mode is always 1).

My question is if there is any toolbox **with code** where we can give a logical formula (LTL formula in my case) and a CFG to check whether the formula satisfies the CFG?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The question is probably too research-specific and probably not related to ML. Imho if this code exists then there would certainly be a research paper mentioning it. And since you certainly know the topic better than anybody here, I wouldn't be too optimistic about the chances of an answer. But who knows, hopefully I'm wrong!

Comment: Also I'm not sure I understand the question, but in case the question is about whether the grammar can generate the formula then it doesn't need to be related to LTL, a general CFG parser is enough (and this is certainly easier to find).

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for replying! Yes, That's what I mean. I need to be able to check whether a formula can be generated by a given CFG.

Comment: Then I think you can use [any CFG parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=cfg+parser+implementation), you just need to represent the grammar in the format required by the system.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for your suggestion!